# continuous or simple in this case?

Tags: continuous

In fact I sent 2 or 3 emails but these were sent to your yahoo address that is why you did not receive them. Then I  realized I **had written** the wrong address .The last one ( the one you received) was with the gmail address.

I was wondering if **had been writing** would be good. I don't think so because if there is a repetition (I sent 2 or 3 emails) which could be justified the continuous aspect the emphasize is more on the completed aspect .

Am I right here ?

Comment: Yes, you could use _I had been writing/using the wrong address_. (You had been habitually sending emails to the person's Yahoo address.)